# Team City > Selenium > Browser Size

Tags: selenium-webdriver, teamcity, resolution

I have teamcity running several hundred selenium tests. Due to some recent UI changes when I run our framework, most of the tests fail.

I have figured out it's because due to a resizing change in our UI if the resolution of a browser is X it changes the nav menu configuration. This is fine and expected now.

The issue is I can't set the resolution of the teamcity "browser" it's set up as a windows service.

I have done some research and found some potential fixes, but most people saying to windows 10 these fixes will no longer work.

Does anyone have a workaround for this issue? Thanks